# Табличные данные вывести в иерархическом виде

Tags: python, база-данных, django, postgresql

Делаю веб-сайт на Django, база данных Postgresql

Есть следующие таблицы в БД:

1. Факультет

   - Id
   - Название
2. Кафедра

   - Id
   - Название
   - **Факультет**
3. Преподаватель

   - Id
   - Имя
   - **Кафедра**
4. Книжные издания

   - **Преподаватель**
   - Название
   - Издатель
   - Год издания

Нужно вывести эти данные на страницу в иерархическом виде:

1. Химический факультет

   1. Кафедра органической химии

      - Садулаев А.Б.
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
      - Богомоев А.П.
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
   2. Кафедра биомолекулярной химии

      - Болтукаев А.А.
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
        Книжное издание этого преподавателя
        ...
      - Махов Б.В.
        ...
2. Механико-математический факультет

   1. Кафедра прикладной математики

      - Колмогоров А.Н.
        ...

Какой лучше способ это сделать?

Я вижу пока один вариант:

Получить все данные в одном sql запросе с помощью inner-join
**Факультет Кафедра Преподаватель Издание**
Химический  Биомолек. Болтукаев  Издание
Химический  Биомолек. Болтукаев  Издание
Химический  Биомолек. Махов      Издание
Математ

Потом результат этого запроса обработать в python и представить его в иерархическом виде (список списков), делая кучу циклов

Comment: А вопрос в чем заключается, раз у вас уже есть решение?

Comment: Есть ли способ лучше это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про шаблонный фильт `regroup` - если я правильно Вас понял, то это то, что Вам нужно

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков Спасибо, regroup тоже пойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это стандартная задача для ORM, тут связи ManyToOne и жадная загрузка.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/
http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/ref/models/querysets.html#prefetch-related

```
data = Факультет.objects.all().prefetch_related('кафедры__преподаватели__издания')
```

А отображать это все просто в цикле

```
for факультет in data:
    for кафедра in факультет.кафедры:
      ...
```

Не знаю как кафедра и факультет правильно перевести на англ. В общем, этом это не задача postgres и делать join не стоит. В текущем примере будет 4 запроса типа:

```
select * from факультеты;
select * from кафедры where id in (...id факультетов);
select * from преподавалите where id in (...id кафедр);
select * from книги where id in (...id преподов);
```

Django все сам распедалит внутри.

Comment: Красавчег! То что надо! Спасибо!